# non-breaking space in link

Tags: html, css, whitespace

In a subnavigation of a Website I try to have the link `Suite «Mont Blanc»`, which was read out of the Backend to be wrapped like this:

> Suite
>   «Mont Blanc»

And not:

> Suite «Mont
>         Blanc»

I know there is `&nbsp;` but if I insert that in the Structure-Element Name (which is listed as a link), the link will not work properly anymore.

Is there a kind of invisible non-breakable space I could use?

Comment: If your code breaks because the textual content of your link has it's spaces turned into `&nbsps`, I think you're doing something very wrong

Comment: Can you explain why an `&nbsp;` in a link should not work? It does indeed, work perfectly: http://jsfiddle.net/fdvoq66k/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/527t5xsx/)**

CSS:

```
span{
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

HTML:

```
Suite
<span>«Mont Blanc» </span>
```

**EDIT:**

If you need span content in next line You can try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/527t5xsx/1/)**

```
span{
    clear:both;
    display:block;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: bad idea to use a generic span rule here

Comment: @Hubert: So you can suggest something better idea here?

Comment: the idea is good, only too generic so that it will affect other parts of any web page. using a more specific css selector (e.g. custom class) or applying the style on individual element is safer

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I don't have idea about OP 's code.. so specified generally.So that OP can use similar method in his code .. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS to prevent wrapping:
`white-space: nowrap;`

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap it in a span like this:

```
Suite<br />
<span style="white-space: nowrap;">«Mont Blanc»</span>
```

The `white-space: nowrap;` CSS prevents wrapping, even if the outer div is smaller than the text.